# Is there a way to split a String and manipulate it in java 8?

Tags: java, string, java-8

I have a requirement to modify an email at runtime in java by add to its name the current time.
I can achieve it like this:

```
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    String email = "song25@gmail.com";
    String[] splitedEmail = email.split("@");
    String newUser = splitedEmail[0] + "-" + localDateTime;
    String newMail = newUser+"@"+splitedEmail[1];
```

Is there a better way, cleaner way, shorter way, to it using java 8? using lambdas or streams?

Comment: If you expect some code to run multiple times, you probably want to use a static Pattern object to split your String.

Comment: @StefanFischer `String.split` will not use a `Pattern` object, when you specify a plain single character pattern.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is already bare bones and optimal.  You could try using the following one-liner:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
String email = "song25@gmail.com";
String newMail = email.replace("@", "-" + localDateTime + "@");
```

Comment: There is no option to do it in java 8? I started to do something like this but it's not finished yet : List<String> splitted = Stream.of(email.split("@")).map(elem -> (elem+"-"+localDateTime)).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Using a stream to do this is overkill IMHO.

Comment: @shayn of course, there is an option to do it in Java 8. This answer shows, how to do it in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex:

```
    String myString = "hello@gmail.com";
    String str = "18_06_2019";
    System.out.println(myString.replaceAll("(\\w*)@", "$1"+str+"@"));
```